# AES encryption different from node and PHP

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

I have two scripts, both using the same algorithm to encrypt a string with same key and IV. But result is different. Is openssl_encrypt still using a different padding scheme than node or am I missing something else hee?

Node

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var passphrase = '29486a7a37664140';
var iv = '76e69938cdf5bb64';
var text = '1234567890123456';

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ctr', passphrase, iv)
var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
crypted += cipher.final('hex');

var result = crypted + ':' + iv;

console.log('crypted: (' + crypted.length + ' chars)', crypted);
// crypted: (32 chars) b94107e56900ec8270a847bbf457eaa6
```

PHP

```
<?php

$encrypt_method = "AES-128-CTR";
$passphrase = '29486a7a37664140';
$iv = '76e69938cdf5bb64';
$text = '1234567890123456';

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt( $text, $encrypt_method, $passphrase, 0, $iv );

echo 'crypted (' . strlen($encrypted) . ' chars): ' . $encrypted;
// crypted (24 chars): uUEH5WkA7IJwqEe79Ffqpg==
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well… stupid. Encoding issue:

changing my node part to use bas64 works

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ctr', passphrase, iv)
var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64')
crypted += cipher.final('base64');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the solution